# how to specify SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES for CreateNamedPipe?

Tags: java, jna, named-pipes

I'm stuck at specifying `SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES` (the last parameter) for `CreateNamedPipe` method. I'd like to allow full access for everyone .

The most in-depth code I could assemble is this:

```
public static HANDLE CreateNamedPipe(String pipeName, PipeDirection pipeDirection, int maxConnections) throws NamedPipeException {
    WinBase.SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES saAttr = new WinBase.SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES();
    saAttr.dwLength = new WinDef.DWORD(saAttr.size());
    saAttr.bInheritHandle = true;
    saAttr.lpSecurityDescriptor = null; // it gives default access rights. I need full control for everyone

    HANDLE handle = Kernel32.INSTANCE.CreateNamedPipe(pipeName,
        pipeDirection.getValue(),
        WinBase.PIPE_TYPE_BYTE | WinBase.PIPE_WAIT,
        maxConnections,
        Integer.MAX_VALUE,
        Integer.MAX_VALUE,
        0,
        saAttr);

    int error = Kernel32.INSTANCE.GetLastError();
    if(error != 0) {
        throw new NamedPipeException(error);
    }
    return handle;
}
```

setting `lpSecurityDescriptor` to `null` gives default access rights but I want full control for everyone.

Answer (score 0):

this is not exactly the full answer, but I hope it helps.

If you don't want to do anything with `saAttr`, then simply place `null` for the last parameter (instead of `saAttr`), and with this the pipe gets a default security descriptor. Citate from Microsoft (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365150(v=vs.85).aspx, *lpSecurityAttributes*):

> The ACLs in the default security descriptor for a named pipe grant full control to the LocalSystem account, administrators, and the creator owner. They also grant read access to members of the Everyone group and the anonymous account.